# Timeline in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

Trying to build a timeline in Flex, Have a horizontal slider when i slide the slider there should be a line on the linechart as a needle moving with respect to value of slider,I Tried using gridlines to achieve this but the grid lines are visible across all the values of x axis,But I want to show only single gridline with respect to value of slider. Is there a way to hide few grid lines and show specific gridlines.

Comment: Instead of trying to bend the chart to your will by using gridlines, why not just draw your vertical line on top of the chart?

Comment: Thanks Sunil, for you response, i have done that too but its difficult to move the line position as i move along  the slider.So its difficult to achieve with that approach, have u done something similar then please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something I created in about 30 minutes. It's very rudimentary, and has some issues that I will leave for you to solve (or you can post a new question specific to the remaining issues). It's likely you'll need to modify this to suit your application anyway, so I didn't bother looking at the remaining issues.

I've assumed you're using `Date` objects for the horizontal axis of the chart. As such you need to convert the date object to it's corresponding numerical value (in epoch time). This allows you to work with the slider component, which expects numbers.

If you do have further questions, I recommend trying to post whatever code you're using (or a simple version of it), that others can run. That way the answers you get will be specific to your case, and not generic like this one :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               creationComplete="onCreationComplete()">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

            import spark.primitives.Line;

            [Bindable] private var chartData : ArrayCollection =
                new ArrayCollection(
                    [
                        { sales: 101000, month: new Date( '01/01/2013' ) },
                        { sales: 350000, month: new Date( '02/01/2013' ) },
                        { sales: 475000, month: new Date( '03/01/2013' ) },
                        { sales: 425000, month: new Date( '04/01/2013' ) }
                    ] );

            private var line:Line;

            private function onCreationComplete():void
            {
                line = new Line();
                line.height = chart.height;
                line.stroke = new SolidColorStroke(0x0000FF, 2);
                chartContainer.addElement(line);            }

            private function getDateInEpochTime(date:Date):Number
            {
                return date.time;
            }

            private function dataTipFormatFunction(value:Number):Object
            {
                return new Date(value).toString();
            }

            private function onSliderChange():void
            {
                line.x = convertSliderValueToXCoordinate();
            }

        private function convertSliderValueToXCoordinate():Number
        {
            var min:Number = slider.minimum;
            var max:Number = slider.maximum;
            var adjustedValue:Number = slider.value - min;
            var range:Number = max - min;
            var percentOfRange:Number = adjustedValue/range
            var xCoordinate:Number = slider.width * percentOfRange;
            var thumbWidth:Number = slider.thumb.width;
            if (percentOfRange > .5)
                xCoordinate = xCoordinate - (thumbWidth * (percentOfRange - .5));
            else if (percentOfRange < .5)
                xCoordinate = xCoordinate + (thumbWidth * (.5 - percentOfRange));
            return xCoordinate;
        }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Group id="chartContainer" width="800" height="600">
        <mx:LineChart id="chart" dataProvider="{chartData}" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="20">
            <mx:horizontalAxis>
                <mx:DateTimeAxis id="hAxis" dataUnits="months" alignLabelsToUnits="true" displayLocalTime="true"/>
            </mx:horizontalAxis>
            <mx:series>
                <mx:LineSeries displayName="Sales by Month" yField="sales" xField="month">
                    <mx:lineStroke>
                        <s:SolidColorStroke color="0xFF0000" />
                    </mx:lineStroke> 
                </mx:LineSeries> 
            </mx:series>
        </mx:LineChart>
        <s:HSlider id="slider" left="0" right="0" bottom="0"
                   dataTipFormatFunction="dataTipFormatFunction"
                   minimum="{getDateInEpochTime(chartData.getItemAt(0).month)}"
                   maximum="{getDateInEpochTime(chartData.getItemAt( chartData.length -1 ).month)}"
                   change="onSliderChange()"/>
    </s:Group>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: Thanks Sunil This is what i am looking for, But there are some changes in it on the horizontal axis need to design the timeline in form of minutes, if a user gives input as time between  6 to 7 then the time line(horizontal axis) should show like 6:00 6:01 .. till 7:00.

Comment: I have completed modifying my timeline as per my requirement if anyone  need this sort of thing  can contact me.

Comment: Hi Sunil, Need help in display the(TimeStamp) values on the x axis of the chart and every 60 seconds the scroll bar and the line should automatically move along the xaxis. Please can you help me on this.

Comment: @user1418852 I think you should post a new question that: shows the code you are using, explains the problems you are having, and details what you have tried. I'm happy to help, but I'd rather not spend another half hour making guesses about what you want to find out that it wasn't what you wanted :) Also, others may be able to help too.

Comment: Hi Sunil, I need a small help in the example that u had shared, On dragging the slider to the end the line doesnt be in synch with the slider it moves away and it creates a difference. Can u help me in resolving it.the line should be center to the slider thumb always.

Comment: @user1418852 Yeah, the solution was quite rudimentary. The line needs to be offset by the width of the slider thumb. But it also seems to vary based on how close the slider thumb is to either extreme. Editing my answer and replacing the `convertSliderValueToXCoordinate()` method with a new variation that accounts for that. It may not be quite perfect, but is close...

Comment: thanks for your response, is there any way where we can build a component by combining both the slider and line together or vrule so that they be in perfect sync to thumb.

Comment: @user1418852, yes, it's definitely possible. And I'm sure the results would be better than trying to bend the pre-existing components into behaving the way you want. I'm available on a contract basis if you'd like to hire me :)